# AngularJS conflicting with Bootstrap tabs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the JavaScript Bootstrap 3 tabs as documented, like this:

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a href="#settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
</div>
```

But with Angular, it's changing the URL to /#/profile for instance..

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Are you using Angular's routing?

Comment: Side question: if you're using Angular and you're also using bootstrap, why aren't you using angular bootstrap (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At one point, if a link had the `_target` attribute set, angular wouldn't intercept those clicks. Perhaps that will work in this case?

Answer (score 26):

Just put `data-target` instead of `href` attribute and it will work without changing urls.

Comment: I was facing a similar issue while working with a wordpress theme. I was using href for tabbed navigation using bootstrap. This answer helped me.I changed href to data-target and it got the tabbed navigation working. Works like charm..

Comment: Angular was intercepting the #hrefs I set on my bootstrap nav-tabs. Changing the href attribute to data-target fixed it for me! thanks mgalic! (although it bugs me just a little bit that now I have <a> tags without href attributes :/ oh well)

Comment: Great solution. @Jupo: If you want to have the hrefs there so that the mouse cursor has the correct styling you still can. Just set an empty value for href and then use the data-target to do the actual navigation. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/a for more info.

Comment: @pbuchheit -- You answered my cursor question before I could even ask it. Thanks!